# ODBC Source (connected to Oracle) in a SSIS package keeps running (without error)

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, visual-studio-2019

I created a new SSIS package with a ODBC source (Oracle) to an OLE DB Destination (MSSQL). During the setup of the source, I could 'preview' the data, so I assume that the connection to Oracle is ok. When the package runs, the ODBC Source block keeps 'running' without stop (I limited the query to a thousand rows)

[image]

- There is not any error or warning message
- I have another package in the same solution reading from Informix and loading the data to the same MSSQL database without issue.

What should I try?
Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the SQL sent to Oracle? The picture is meaningless in determining any root cause.

Comment: And what happens if you run the query on Oracle on its own?

Comment: The query is a simple SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE fielddatexyz >- SYSDATE -1. Outside SSIS the query runs ok (Oracle SQL Developer, Excel with ODBC  connection) I get just 525 rows. Even when I setup the ODBC Source I see the data preview. Just that when I run the package, keeps loading without error or anything else

Comment: update: now i tried and it works, but when I change it to SYSDATE -2, it has the same problem. The difference of rows is 525 vs 599, so there is not a big difference in the amount of data. Maybe some row corrupted? but without error or warning I don't know how to proceed

Comment: Try using the Microsoft Connector for Oracle. The `MS Oracle Source` and `MS Oracle Destination` tasks work better than the generic ODBC versions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/oracle-connector?view=sql-server-ver16